# How to get element value and assign it to a Double using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to get the value of all 3 "avg" values from the following xml, and then assign them to a double array. using linq to xml. I'm brand new to linq to xml, so i'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Here is my current code

```
var q = from e in xDoc.Descendants("sell")
        select new
        {
            result = e.Element("avg").Value
        };
```

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<evec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
    <marketstat>
        <type id="626">
            <buy>
                <volume>11</volume>
                <avg>9345454.55</avg>
                <max>11500000.00</max>
                <min>7500000.00</min>
                <stddev>1862495.34</stddev>
                <median>7600000.00</median>
                <percentile>11500000.00</percentile>
            </buy>
            <sell>
                <volume>23</volume>
                <avg>18749987.25</avg>
                <max>18749987.25</max>
                <min>18749987.25</min>
                <stddev>0.00</stddev>
                <median>18749987.25</median>
                <percentile>18749987.25</percentile>
            </sell>
            <all>
                <volume>34</volume>
                <avg>15707344.32</avg>
                <max>18749987.25</max>
                <min>7500000.00</min>
                <stddev>4573474.77</stddev>
                <median>18749987.25</median>
                <percentile>7500000.00</percentile>
            </all>
        </type>
    </marketstat>
</evec_api>
```

Comment: Do you want to know where each one of them came from or just a simple `double[]` as a result?. Also please provide what you have tried already to do. There are many examples on linq to xml

Comment: BTW, the downvotes that you got are probably because when you posted the question you didn't explain what you have tried. You just said "I need X".. which isn't the way SO works. You must show some effort and we can help from there

Comment: @GiladGreen Thanks, i'll keep that in mind for future questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem with your code above is that you are retrieving only the value of one of the `avg`s. Using the `Descendants` you can find all the `avg`s and then get the value:

```
var result = xDoc.Descendants("avg").Select(e => (double)e);
```

---

If you want to be sure that it is a `double` and not fail on and InvalidCast then use `double.TryParse`: *Keep in mind that this has a side effect through the use of the `value`. If you do not want to do so you can use `TryParse` for the `where` and then again a `Parse` in the `select`*

```
double value = 0;
var result = (from element in xDoc.Descendants("avg")
              where double.TryParse(element.Value, out value)
              select value).ToList();

// result: 9345454.55, 18749987.25, 15707344.32
```

If you want the result to also have some assassination between the number and from where it came you can use the `.Parent` property:

```
double value = 0;
var result = (from element in xDoc.Descendants("avg")
              where  double.TryParse(element.Value, out value)
              select new
              {
                  Tag = element.Parent.Name.LocalName,
                  Value = value
              }).ToList();
```

---

[image]

Comment: This seems to be only returning the last value.

Comment: Sorry, heres the code i am using to return the value:                         Output.Text = Convert.ToString(getResultPrices.value);

Comment: @Antono - I tested it before posting. Please check agaon

Comment: Nope, looking at the values result returns a count of 3, however value only returns the last average value

Comment: @AntoniNicyfor - Can you show me the code you are using now? Because I just tested again all options and I get correct data..

Comment: @AntoniNicyfor - It should be Ok..... Can you debug and put a breakpoint on the `where` and check each element?.. I suspect that maybe your given xml has the same values. Also you can check with giving it exactly the xml from the question

Comment: 'element.Value' returns the first Avg value, however 'out value' after it returns the last. I believe I have to get the values from the list that is created, instead of getting the values from the 'value' double

Comment: @AntoniNicyfor - Check update. I've used your code and only changed that instead of getting the xml from a url it takes it from a file which contains the xml you gave in the question. Because the linq iterates synchronously 1 item at a time after the `where` sets it it is used by the `select`. Then next iteration a new value is assigned to that `value` - which does not influence the previous one

Comment: Thank you, I was just assigning `value` to the text box instead of `result`

Comment: That's a very dangerous query. `TryParse()` is _designed_ to cause side effects and you should not rely on those side effects in your linq queries. Even when localized to a method, it's still a very bad pattern to use. Don't do it.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I agree and don't like the side effects myself... However how would you suggest?

Comment: The only reasonable approach to using that method would be to wrap it with another method that does not cause side effects. Instead, return a tuple of the two values. But as this is Linq to XML, you should be casting the element or attribute to the appropriate type as [Chuck](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40163141) has shown.

Comment: @JeffMercado - Agreed. Wanted to delete answer... but now can't

Answer (score 1):

These answers seem awfully verbose. If you want the three `avg` values, and there are only those from the tags `<marketstat><type id="626">` but if there are more marketstat's and type that you want to avoid, you'll have to dig deeper.

```
double[] averages = xDoc.Descendants("avg")
                        .Select(xavg => (double)xavg)
                        .ToArray();
```

For instance,

```
XElement type626 = xDoc.Descendants("type")
                       .First(x => (int)x.Attribute("id") == 626);
```

Then paste the earlier into this, we replace `xDoc` with `type626`.

```
double[] averages = type626.Descendants("avg")
                        .Select(xavg => (double)xavg)
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<evec_api version=""2.0"" method=""marketstat_xml"">
    <marketstat>
        <type id=""626"">
            <buy>
                <volume>11</volume>
                <avg>9345454.55</avg>
                <max>11500000.00</max>
                <min>7500000.00</min>
                <stddev>1862495.34</stddev>
                <median>7600000.00</median>
                <percentile>11500000.00</percentile>
            </buy>
            <sell>
                <volume>23</volume>
                <avg>18749987.25</avg>
                <max>18749987.25</max>
                <min>18749987.25</min>
                <stddev>0.00</stddev>
                <median>18749987.25</median>
                <percentile>18749987.25</percentile>
            </sell>
            <all>
                <volume>34</volume>
                <avg>15707344.32</avg>
                <max>18749987.25</max>
                <min>7500000.00</min>
                <stddev>4573474.77</stddev>
                <median>18749987.25</median>
                <percentile>7500000.00</percentile>
            </all>
        </type>
    </marketstat>
</evec_api>";

            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var typeElement = xdoc.Element("evec_api").Element("marketstat").Element("type");
            var avgElements = typeElement.Elements().Select(e => e.Element("avg"));

            foreach (var avgElement in avgElements)
                Console.WriteLine(avgElement.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB .Net I would do

```
    Dim avgs() As Double = xe...<avg>.Select(Function(a) CDbl(a.Value)).ToArray
```

which in C# looks like this (according to the converter I used)

```
double[] avgs = xe.Select(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.Value)).ToArray;
```

Tested with

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load from a file
    '  xe = XElement.Load("Your Path Here")

    ' for testing
    xe = <evec_api version="2.0" method="marketstat_xml">
             <marketstat>
                 <type id="626">
                     <buy>
                         <volume>11</volume>
                         <avg>9345454.55</avg>
                         <max>11500000.00</max>
                         <min>7500000.00</min>
                         <stddev>1862495.34</stddev>
                         <median>7600000.00</median>
                         <percentile>11500000.00</percentile>
                     </buy>
                     <sell>
                         <volume>23</volume>
                         <avg>18749987.25</avg>
                         <max>18749987.25</max>
                         <min>18749987.25</min>
                         <stddev>0.00</stddev>
                         <median>18749987.25</median>
                         <percentile>18749987.25</percentile>
                     </sell>
                     <all>
                         <volume>34</volume>
                         <avg>15707344.32</avg>
                         <max>18749987.25</max>
                         <min>7500000.00</min>
                         <stddev>4573474.77</stddev>
                         <median>18749987.25</median>
                         <percentile>7500000.00</percentile>
                     </all>
                 </type>
             </marketstat>
         </evec_api>
```